# Most correct translation of this Bulgarian phrase - "политическа поръчка"?

Tags: word-choice

Both usually translate to "order" in English, but "поръчка" means order as in "to receive an **order** from a customer" while "заповед" means order as in "to obey an **order**". Which meaning of "order" is meant in English is usually inferred by context, but I was having difficulty translating the phrase "политическа поръчка", as in:

> Президентът твърди че съдията който го разследва изпълнява политическа **поръчка**.

This would translate as:

> The President maintains that the Judge who investigates him is fulfilling a political **order**.

Here I feel like a subtle meaning is lost, because order becomes ambiguous - while the English translation would strongly imply order as in obeying order from someone who you owe "allegance" to, the original Bulgarian implies something more transactional - fullfilling somebody's request, either as a favor or for some compensation.

Is there a good way to translate the above sentence so that order unambiguously means a "customer's" order in this context?

I was thinking about "request", or "errand". Actually "errand" comes closest but then you have to say "running an errand" which in this context would just sound odd.

Would "fulfilling a political errand" sound good?

Comment: We don't "fulfill" an errand. You could say the judge was "doing the bidding" of a political party, or that the judge "had a political agenda".   To "do someone's *bidding*" is to do what they have ordered (or requested).

Comment: I'm not clear what distinction you're trying to make. Both contexts in your first paragraph use ***order*** with the sense of ***instruction, command*** - it's just that with *customer* orders we know they're always instructions to sell/deliver a ***product***. But a *political* order could be whatever makes sense in the exact context. Presumably if someone says the judge is "fulfilling a political order", he means the judge is doing what some politicians told him to do, OR his focus is on the political rather than the *legal* aspects of a case.

Comment: Perhaps "following a political agenda". I'm not sure where 'customer' comes in – are you wanting a meaning unlike everything else you said?

Comment: Is the sentence supposed to be criticizing the judge, by saying that they're unduly influenced by political considerations? Or is it praising the judge, by saying that they're acting in accordance with their responsibilities?

Comment: I think you're heading in the wrong direction to begin with. A political demand would not be considered like a customer order. A customer order is a list of products being purchased, not a demand to perform some activity.

Comment: Perhaps 'requirement' is a closer synonym.

Comment: "fulfilling a political transaction."  Transaction implies a requested service by some entity.

Comment: You're looking for a synonym for 'order' in the first sense that you describe, i.e. "to receive an order from a customer", but fitting the example sentence? So 'decree' or 'demand' are out?

Comment: "Doing a political favour" maybe sounds more natural.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you for the insight. Yes, it's kinda difficult to translate exactly, the problem is that in Bulgarian the word can be used (as a noun) to mean "an order for a service" as opposed to just "an order for a product". Here the most correct translation would be "performing a service at the behest of someone", which implies a more equal relationship than obeying someone's order.

Comment: The difference you're talking about is covered in English with ***order = booking = purchase = requisition = commission = ....*** on the one side, and ***order = command = instruction = edict = directive = injunction = behest = ...*** on the other. But I think it's nonsensical to equate the president's dismissal of the judge as having anything to do with customer's purchase orders. He's obviously saying the judge is following the ***instructions*** of wheelers and dealers in the political party who gave him his job in the first place.